# codeigniter textfield with disappearing default text

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating a form using codeigniter, I wanted to know whether there is a way that we can create atext field having a default text and as soon as user clicks on that field the default text disappears. I was wondering whether there is any method in codeigniter that allows us to do this?

Thanks
Any efforts will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important Note: This solution was posted many years ago and is no longer applicable. Please see the edits below for an alternative solution using HTML5.**

You need jQuery for DOM functionalities. The cool thing about jQuery is that many of the functionalities we see everyday on Web 2.0 sites already have their jQuery plugin counterparts. BTW, Codeigniter is a PHP framework while jQuery is javascript framework so you won't be needing Codeigniter for this specific feature.

What you need is an in-label plugin for jQuery. This is the best I've tried so far: http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/

As for the code this is basically the only thing you need:

```
$("label").inFieldLabels();
```

Instead of removing the text outright, it fades the inline label slowly or until you type in something. Check it out.

---

**To date, the solution above is no longer necessary. using HTML5, users can use the following HTML codes:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name here" />
```

Comment: Always a pleasure. I like your question, by the way. It's unique and very interesting. I actually didn't remember using this feature again until now. +2 on your question and comment. ;)

Comment: Thanks! that is great ... on top of that just one line does it all ... great answew hope I could upvote twice

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use html5 property `placeholder` for this if you don't need it work in older browsers and IE.

Another option would be to use javascript like Jhourlad Estrella suggests.